# Can we use Datastax Enterprise Opscenter with existing Apache cluster?

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, opscenter, datastax-startup

So we just joined the Datastax startup program, and have an existing cluster of Apache Cassandra nodes. We'd like to use some of the enterprise features of opscenter, like continuous repair and rebalancing data.

In order to utilize those, do we need to be running a Datastax Enterprise Cluster, or can we just run Datastax Enterprise Opscenter on our existing nodes?

Comment: Yes you must upgrade to use this functionality